# python output for addition

Tags: python, input, output, addition

I'm new to python (version 2.7) and I want to know how I can input two numbers on a single line and calculate the sum of both numbers. I'm looking for the output to read like this:

11 + 11 = 22

The input would look like this:

11 11

Comment: Use `raw_input` and `str.split`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
a = raw_input("Enter numbers separated by space: ").split() # input() for Python3 
print ' + '.join(a) + ' = ' + str(sum(map(int, a)))         # print() for Python3
```

Output:

```
Enter numbers separated by space: 2 34 234
2 + 34 + 234 = 270
```

---

OR Here's something different:

```
def add():
    ans = None
    while ans not in ['q', 'quit', '']:
        ans = input('> ')
        print(sum(map(int, ans.strip().split(' ')))

add()
```

And, here are the explanations:

```
def add():
    ans = None
    while ans not in ['q', 'quit', '']: # stops if you type 'q', 'quit', or nothing
        ans = input('> ') # for python 3
        ans = raw_input('> ') # for python 2
        # it asks the user for a string
        ans.strip() # remove the spaces at the end and at the beginning of the string
        ans.split(' ') # splits the string each time it sees a space (so, you get a list)
        map(int, ans.strip().split(' ') # because we splited a string, we have a list of string.
        # Here, we transform them to integer, so we can add them. map() calls a function (here
        # int) on every element of the array we passed as the second argument
        sum(...) # sum is a function that takes a list and adds every number that it contains
        print(...) # you know what that does ;)
        # not that one python 2, you don't need the parentheses 

add() # call our function
```

Answer (score -2):

since you're new to the language, I think a simpler answer is best. So the way I would go about it is

```
nums = input("Enter two integers: ")
nums.split(' ')
print nums[0]
print nums[1]
print '11 ','+ ','11 ','=', 11+11

# OR

nums = input("Enter two integers: ")
numList = nums.split(',')
nums = [int(x) for x in numList]
print '11',' + ','11',' = ', nums[0]+nums[1]
```